# Как в питоне проверить вводимое значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проверка должна быть на буквы и отсутствие цифр и других символов, а также на наличие кириллицы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558392/how-to-check-if-character-in-string-is-a-letter-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x = input("Введите значение: ")

r = re.search(r'^[а-яА-ЯеЁ]+$', x) #допускает только кириллицу
r = re.search(r'^[а-яА-ЯеЁa-zA-Z]+$', x) #допускает кириллицу и латиницу

answer = x if r else False #записывает в переменную строку из input, если она прошла проверку, иначе False

print(answer)
```

Comment: как можно ещё сделать проверку на отсутствие цифр и других знаков?

Comment: Код в ответе не пропускает ничего, кроме букв (т.е. точек, пробелов и т.д. он не пропустит в ответ). Или вам что-то другое нужно? Поясните

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы при вводе input он "сканировал" введённое значение на наличие кириллицы и отсутствие других символов.

Comment: Пардон, мой код пропускает пробельные символы, не досмотрел, сейчас поправлю ответ.